# How to retrieve custom field values from JIRA with C#?

Tags: c#, jira

There are some default values present in the custom field called "PLACE" which has LONDON,PARIS etc.. How can i retrieve these ( London , paris ) from JIRA SOAP API in C#. JIRA- JIRA 4.0 and C# - .net framework 4.0.

Comment: I don't think the default values for custom fields are available in the JIRA 4.0 SOAP API. Perhaps in JIRA 5.x REST API?

Comment: I've added some code (python, though it's not really hard to translate to C#) using `XML-RPC`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [XML-RPC](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+XML-RPC+Overview) to do that, if you're not set on the SOAP API. Python Code sample (can change to C#):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Refer to the XML-RPC Javadoc to see what calls are available:
# http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/xmlrpc/XmlRpcService.html

import xmlrpclib

# Jira connction info
#server = 'http://212.29.248.203:8080/rpc/xmlrpc'
server = 'https://your.jira.com/rpc/xmlrpc'
user = 'user'
password = 'password'
filter = '10302'
customfieldID = "customfield_10417"

s = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(server)
auth = s.jira1.login(user, password)

# get list of issues
issues = s.jira1.getIssuesFromFilter(auth, filter)
for issue in issues:
        # get open since time
        for customFields in issue['customFieldValues']:
                if customFields['customfieldId'] == customfieldID :
                        print "found field!"+  customFields['values']
```